# Data filtering performance with dict comprehension

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, filter, dictionary-comprehension

While trying to find the most efficient way to filter dictionaries, I stumbled upon a strange behaviour.

I made 4 tests, the first one filters the dictionary sequentially.

The second one does a single filtering with a combination of the rules (which is actually the most efficient way).

Then, I made attempt to make it more generic so that the filter may be used with an arbitrary number of predicates, that could be eventually user-defined, not hard-coded.

And I realised that combining predicated with `all` was much more inefficient than doing two filterings one after the other.

What can explain this ? Is this the `all()` function that has poor performance ?
Would you suggest any other way to improve performance still in a generic way ?

```
# TEST 1 (Took 1.717677354812622s)
y = {k:x for k,x in y.items() if x['id'] >= 3 }
y = {k:x for k,x in y.items() if x['name'].find('a') != -1 }


# TEST 2 (Took 1.411365032196045s)
y = {k:x for k,x in y.items() if x['id'] >= 3 and x['name'].find('a') != -1  }

# TEST 3 (Took 3.4738941192626953s)
predicates = [
    lambda x: x['id'] >= 3,
    lambda x: x['name'].find('a') != -1
]
y = {k:x for k,x in y.items() if all([f(x) for f in predicates]) }

# TEST 4 (Took 2.4156315326690674s)
predicates = [
    lambda x: x['id'] >= 3,
]
y = {k:x for k,x in y.items() if predicates[0](x) }
predicates = [
    lambda x: x['name'].find('a') != -1
]
y = {k:x for k,x in y.items() if predicates[0](x) }
```

Testing bench :

```
from var_dump import var_dump
import time

start_time = time.time()

for p in range(0,1000000):
    users = {
        1: {'id': 1, 'name': "toto"},
        2: {'id': 2, 'name': "titi"},
        3: {'id': 3, 'name': "tata"},
        4: {'id': 4, 'name': "tutu"},
        5: {'id': 5, 'name': "john"},
        6: {'id': 6, 'name': "jane"}
    }

    y = users

    #-> test goes here

print(y)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: `all` applies both lambdas on every dict value, whereas in TEST2 the condition `if x['id'] >= 3 and x['name'].find('a') != -1` is evaluated lazily, `x['name'].find('a')` is not evaluated for ids < 3 (50% less checks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`all` evaluates both conditions, whereas `and` in TEST_2 is evaluated lazily which means the second condition is evaluated for ids >= 3 only.
Illustrating by simple print statements:

```
users = {
    1: {'id': 1, 'name': "toto"},
    2: {'id': 2, 'name': "titi"},
    3: {'id': 3, 'name': "tata"},
    4: {'id': 4, 'name': "tutu"},
    5: {'id': 5, 'name': "john"},
    6: {'id': 6, 'name': "jane"}
}

def check_1(item):
    print("check_1")
    return item['id'] >= 3

def check_2(item):
    print("check_2")
    return item['name'].find('a') != -1


# all condition
print("TEST AND")
for k, v in users.items():
    check_1(v) and check_2(v)

# all condition
print("TEST ALL")
for k, v in users.items():
    all([check_1(v), check_2(v)])
```

Out:

```
TEST AND
check_1
check_1
check_1
check_1
check_2
check_1
check_2
check_1
check_2
TEST ALL
check_1
check_2
check_1
check_2
check_1
check_2
check_1
check_2
check_1
check_2
check_1
check_2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is due to using a generator expression as was answered in this question [Python: any() unexpected performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44802682/python-any-unexpected-performance)

Answer (score 1):

Because you evaluate your predicates between brackets, a list is created and all of the conditions will be checked for all the items: `all([f(x) for f in predicates])`.  This means you're testing the second predicate for more items compared to the other approaches and end up comparing apples to oranges.

The all() function can use a generator, in which case it will stop as soon as one of the condition is False and thus short-circuit the evaluation.  Remove the brackets: `all(f(x) for f in predicates)` and you will be comparing oranges to oranges.

*Note that `x['name'].find('a') != -1` could be replaced with `'a' in x['name']` which would be clearer IMHO*