# Is there a Pythonic way of filtering substrings of strings in a list?

Tags: python, substring

I have a list with strings as below.

```py
candidates = ["Hello", "World", "HelloWorld", "Foo", "bar", "ar"]
```

And I want the list to be filtered as `["HelloWorld", "Foo", "Bar"]`, because others are substrings. I can do it like this, but don't think it's fast or elegant.

```py
def filter_not_substring(candidates):
    survive = []
    for a in candidates:
        for b in candidates:
            if a == b:
                continue
            if a in b:
                break
        else:
            survive.append(a)
    return survive
```

Is there any fast way to do it?

Comment: i dont think there is a faster way then looping though the list twice. There are more elegant ways to write it tho.

Comment: First, presort the input list by increasing length. Testing the shorter substrings against the rest of the list will quikcly get rid of `"Hello", "World", "ar"`

Comment: An approach that would work: a saturating bitfield counter of the number of each letter in the word would work. We could pack it into 64b, using saturating n-bit counters for each letter, tailored to English (or whatever language), using wider bitfields for common letters. If by "Pythonic" you mean "good big-O performance", not "short simple code" or "nice idiomatic code".

Comment: Can there be duplicates in the input?

Comment: And is that a realistic input? You have such tiny lists, which take almost no time, and still need something faster?

Comment: And if there *are* duplicates in the input, your function keeps all of them. Is that intended?

Comment: @KellyBundy input would be distinct, so the result also has no duplication. And **of course**, input on the post is just a sample, I have much more bigger input.

Comment: Without describing the larger cases, and with accepting an answer that doesn't scale well and that emphasizes benchmarks with such small input, it's not "of course" that you have much bigger input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
candidates = ["Hello", "World", "HelloWorld", "Foo", "bar", "ar"]
result = [c for c in candidates if not any(c in o and len(o) > len(c) for o in candidates)]
print(result)
```

Counter to what was suggested in the comments:

```
from timeit import timeit


def filter_not_substring(candidates):
    survive = []
    for a in candidates:
        for b in candidates:
            if a == b:
                continue
            if a in b:
                break
        else:
            survive.append(a)
    return survive


def filter_not_substring2a(candidates):
    return [c for c in candidates if not any(len(o) > len(c) and c in o for o in candidates)]


def filter_not_substring2b(candidates):
    return [c for c in candidates if not any(c in o and len(o) > len(c) for o in candidates)]


xs = ["Hello", "World", "HelloWorld", "Foo", "bar", "ar", "bar"]
print(filter_not_substring(xs), filter_not_substring2a(xs), filter_not_substring2b(xs))
print(timeit(lambda: filter_not_substring(xs)))
print(timeit(lambda: filter_not_substring2a(xs)))
print(timeit(lambda: filter_not_substring2b(xs)))
```

Result:

```
['HelloWorld', 'Foo', 'bar', 'bar'] ['HelloWorld', 'Foo', 'bar', 'bar'] ['HelloWorld', 'Foo', 'bar', 'bar']
1.5163685
4.6516653
3.8334089999999996
```

So, OP's solution is substantially faster, but `filter_not_substring2b` is still about 20% faster than `2a`. So, putting the `len` comparison first doesn't save time.

For any production scenario, OP's function is probably optimal - a way to speed it up might be to bring the whole problem into C, but I doubt that would show great gains, since the logic is pretty straightforward already and I'd expect Python to do a fairly good job of it as well.

User @ming noted that OP's solution can be improved a bit:

```
def filter_not_substring_b(candidates):
    survive = []
    for a in candidates:
        for b in candidates:
            if a in b and a != b:
                break
        else:
            survive.append(a)
    return survive
```

This version of the function is somewhat faster, for me about 10-15%

Finally, note that this is only *just* faster than `2b`, even though it is very similar to the optimised solution by @ming, but almost 3x slower than their solution. It's unclear to me why that would be - if anyone has fairly certain thoughts on that, please share in the comments:

```
def filter_not_substring_c(candidates):
    return [a for a in candidates if all(a not in b or a == b for b in candidates)]
```

Comment: i doubt this would be any faster.

Comment: I think you're right - might be considered more "elegant", for whatever that's worth.

Comment: Shouldn't you perform the length check before performing the substring check if you're trying to use short-circuit evaluation?

Comment: In fact, it's not just short-circuiting, it's preventing every string from being removed because every string is its own substring. For speed, putting the `len` comparison after the `in` comparison is in fact faster, by about 20%

Comment: @Grismar elegance would be subjective, but as @ BrokenBenchmark said, the length before substring check would make it faster.

Comment: I found that using OP's solution `filter_not_substring()`, replacing the content inside for loop with `if a in b and a != b: break`, will be ~18% even faster

Comment: I accidentally un-upvoted @ming their comment, but that's what I was seeing as well - it is a substantial improvement.

Comment: First, presort the input list by increasing length. Then you don't even need to explicitly test `len(o) > len(c)`.

Comment: @smci presorting the list is even slower than the test, because the same test would have to be performed many times still, while creating a new data structure - I tried it, but it made it worse.

Comment: I believe there are two reasons that using comprehension with `any()`/`all()` is slower than simple loop with break. Firstly, "breaking" the loop with condition allow the loop to stop when certain condition is met, instead of needing to process all items as in the comprehension. Secondly, there are quite some computation overhead on `any`/`all`. You could try removing the code "any" and "all" and compare the performance (of course the result will be incorrect). Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44802682/python-any-unexpected-performance

Comment: @Grismar: presorting the list **by length** should be fast. It's not a general alphabetical sort.

Comment: @smci - you're welcome to try it, I have and you're wrong about the speedup (i.e. `candidates = sorted(candidates, key=len)`) @ming the reason I find that surprising is that both `any` and `all` do short-circuit, so they don't process the entire comprehension (or shouldn't); removing the `any` in fact makes it slow down even more, so the primary cause of the slowness appears to lie in the comprehension vs. list construction using `.append()` in this case, which is surprising to me, more so because there's the overhead of function calls to a proper function like `.append()` here.

Comment: @Ming [Another reason/improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68938628) for slow `any`.

Comment: I do get a nice [speedup with sorting](https://tio.run/##tVLLbsMgELzzFducjGTl0ksVydeqf9BDZCEw6xYFA1pwlHy9a3AejZq0p@4BdncG2BkRjunTu@eXQNPUkx8gmQFNAjMET@lUMcY09tAbm5CE80nEUcVExn0IVXXSaaNlwsg3DOaII@3NHqGBbVsavSeQYBxcqQvzDKpHYA7TL4cVzIQ5fWpA3TJyKEK5u3TRRrzlnIZayxDQ6UryghKmkdwZ/EVm91PmtTErjbNbqL@RatjhsbHo@B@eEO6R4s1Zfsed0wUPrPkvP/rRdVnedpn57geoH2NdzVp2KBes3tBav6ph9e7J6pyUzqV69QVVkvK2rLloWfYgD5KVloEWJWF@IlXLD62sHJSWm4JXh8h5XdK1EE4OKASfpi8). Also @smci